# Selenium webdriver: Text field with default value not getting cleared

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

I have to enter the date in a text field in the form. The text field is populated with the current date by default. So I cleared the field using

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))).sendKeys(date);
```

It was working fine for some iterations. But in a continuous loop mode, the clear function is not working. Which in short will make the field remain with the current date.
I'm using selenium web driver with firefox

Comment: OR.getProperty(object)) what do you get when calling it? Also please provide the proper HTML source if you need help

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='IDOFINPUT']")).clear();

Comment: How are you saying that the clear function is not working? The new date you are entering gets appended to the current date present on the input field?

Comment: A link to the site would be most helpful. Short of that, you could try sending the CTRL+A command and then use `.sendKeys()` to overwrite the current date. Without being able to see the site it's hard to help in cases like this.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. The OR.getProperty(object))  is the object repository. In short the locator be it xpath or id or any valid webdriver locator

Comment: @JeffC Thank you for your suggestion. I'm not so sure whether it is solved or not. But the problem have not seen for a while

Answer (score 0):

In a loop, you might possibly face clearing before the date sets so avoid this you should add some waiting before clearing the date in the text field. The easiest way is to add `sleep` but the better approach add `wait until`. see below:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))).sendKeys(date);
```

You should find the xpath/css selector inside the text box then wait until it loads:

```
WebDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//* ...")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))).sendKeys(date);
```